# Get all server variables in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to fetch a list of all server variables in ASP.NET Core. Back in the ASP.NET days, you could simply use the list available on `Request.ServerVariables`. To my knowledge, ASP.NET Core doesn't have a similar construct. You can do this:

```cs
var serverVariables = httpContext.Features.Get<IServerVariablesFeature>();
var value = serverVariables["AUTH_USER"];
```

to get a single user variable. I also know about the extension method fetching a single variable from the HTTP context. But there doesn't seem to be a way to fetch all variables without being explicit about the names like this:

```cs
private const string ServerVariableNames = "APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH,AUTH_USER,AUTH_TYPE,...";
var serverVariables = ServerVariableNames.Split(new[] { ',' }).Select(name => new {name, value = serverVariablesFeature[name])));
```

With this solution, I need to list all server variables manually.

There's the `ALL_HTTP` variable but that one only includes request headers and not server variables like `SERVER_NAME` and `SERVER_SOFTWARE`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need *all* server variables? Or *any* server variables? What are you going to do with variables you know nothing about? The variable names you used are specific to IIS but **many** ASP.NET Core applications are self-hosted, running in containers, usually on Linux. Some of these variables, like authentication variables, shouldn't even be available outside the authentication page and have no meaning when modern authentication methods are used.

Comment: I simply want to log all server variables on a failing request. Your comments around hosting outside IIS is a good example of why I don't want to hardcode the list of names.

Comment: That's a *very* different question. The real question is how to log request and server settings, not retrieve server variables. The variables you posted are not just specific to IIS only, they're specific to *some versions* of IIS. IIS Express doesn't have the same variables. Other host won't have *any* variables. Passwords should NEVER BE LOGGED.

Comment: I'd say the *real* question is how to configure your logging library to log request/server settings. Possibly on top of increasing the log details already logged by ASP.NET Core itself.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing here. I simply want a list of server variables without pointing them out manually. It's not a different question from what I asked IMO. Request settings/headers are easy (`Request.Headers`). But those are not the variables in question.

Comment: Also, I have replaced `AUTH_PASSWORD` with `AUTH_USER` in the example. Those names only serve as an example.

Comment: This is not working anymore in asp.net core. Use Headers instead as stated in above comments.

Comment: But headers doesn't include the server variables. `Request.Headers` return variables like `Accept`, `Connection`, and `Host` which is fine. But the server variables are still supported and working perfectly fine in ASP.NET Core using the `IServerVariablesFeature`. My only issue here is that I cannot iterate over the server variables with this interface. Only get single variables by name - one by one.

Comment: You're still asking about the Y, the assumed solution, not X, how to add details to the log. The assumed solution is wrong and won't even work if a server has no server variables. That's why this is called a ServerVariables*Feature*. To solve the *real* problem, check eg [how Serilog logs requests and enriches the log from the HttpContext](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#request-logging). The [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) contains the information you want.

Comment: The [Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontext.features?view=aspnetcore-5.0) property in HttpContext contains any uncommon server or request features added by the server or middleware. I have to repeat this: `Server Variables` is a feature specific to IIS only. It's not available in other servers or even while debugging. It won't be available if you run the web app from the command line

Comment: I know. I simply want to log them if there.

Comment: The interface was explicitly built to *prevent* this. Which is a very good idea, since logging everything would also log sensitive information to an unprotected sink. There are far better ways to get that information. The user-specific information isn't even accurate as only the login POST will contain authentication information. All subsequent requests will use cookies or tokens, and the user will only be available through `HttpContext.User`

Comment: It makes sense to not include sensitive information here - agree. I just want to log information if there. If a user hosts my website on a range of different IIS servers, it would be a benefit to have the log include a server variable like `SERVER_SOFTWARE`. I know that this wouldn't include any value on other web servers unless this is supported by each server. So, someone using a self-hosted process on Linux wouldn't see this. But others that host on IIS would.

Comment: But I see your point. There's a lot of headers available on the request. It's probably just a few ones I'm missing when hosting this on IIS. I can add those manually. Thank you for your time on this 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to get all variables with `IServerVariablesFeature`. Under the hood there is [IISHttpContext](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Servers/IIS/IIS/src/Core/IISHttpContext.FeatureCollection.cs) implementing this interface and logic for retrieving server variables is the following

```
string? IServerVariablesFeature.this[string variableName]
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(variableName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(variableName)} should be non-empty string");
        }

        // Synchronize access to native methods that might run in parallel with IO loops
        lock (_contextLock)
        {
            return NativeMethods.HttpTryGetServerVariable(_requestNativeHandle, variableName, out var value) ? value : null;
        }
    }
    //... setter
}
```

[Native methods](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Servers/IIS/IIS/src/NativeMethods.cs):

```
//...
internal const string AspNetCoreModuleDll = "aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll";

[DllImport(AspNetCoreModuleDll)]
private static extern int http_get_server_variable(
    NativeSafeHandle pInProcessHandler,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string variableName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out string value);

public static bool HttpTryGetServerVariable(NativeSafeHandle pInProcessHandler, string variableName, out string value)
{
    return http_get_server_variable(pInProcessHandler, variableName, out value) == 0;
}

//...
```

So I thought that `aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll` might contain a function to get all variables but after inspecting its exported functions I found only 2 method working with variables `http_get_server_variable` and `http_set_server_variable`

[image: asp net core module]